# IE7 renders weird, need a little help

Tags: css, css-float, internet-explorer-7

IE8,9, FF, Safari and Chrome work perfect but IE7 is being a son of a-biotch. At [This page](http://www.polestardistribution.com) you can see that the right sidebar is well below what it is in any other browser.

The footer on the interior pages is bumping up too high as well, tried to clear it but it won't work in ie7.

I'm using ie7 conditional statement hacks because it renders properly in other browsers.

Doesn't have to follow standards, just needs to render right.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: FYI...I see differences in IE8 also. The right hand side bar and the footer.

Comment: Ok...after refreshing the IE8 rendering looks like it does in chrome. Don't know what was going on, but can't repro...so disregard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did to figure this thing out. I just made a new container id #containermain and made it 940px and floated the right sidebar right. done and done.

Answer (score 0):

your css is really strange/different to how I would normally work so I'm not sure of repercussions of what I say here. Just a disclaimer :)

It seems to me that IE7 is actually rendering the most correct version since you #container is collapsing. The #container takes up the full width of the content and so the #rightsidebar appear below. A quick fix (may need some additional tweaks) is:

```
#container {
   width:705px;
   float:left;
   margin:0px;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set widths on your left and center columns (both of which are set to float:left) Why are you not floating your right hand column left ?

I have seen IE7 freak out in situations such as these, I don't know why it is all I can say is its IE.